# What is distribution of sum of two geometric distribution?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Problem: We are tossing an unfair coin (the probability of throwing a head is $p$). We count the number of the first identic throws (for example, if we have HHHT..., then this number is three). What is the distribution of this random number?

my idea:
The count of $k$ identic throws will either be $k$ Hs and one more T or $k$ Ts and one more K. so I got:
$$P(n=k)=p^k\cdot(1-p)+(1-p)^k\cdot p$$

which looks like two geometric distribution adding together.

But I can see no known distribution out of this form and I do not know how I should transform this expression. I also wonder if this is a distribution after all, as it consists of two geometric distribution and the sum of probability will be $1+1=2$..?

Comment: The sum of two probabilities for disjoint events is the probability of the union of the events. I doubt this distribution has a name.

Comment: Concerning terminology: Saying that this is "distribution of sum of two geometric distributions" is somewhat misleading. That would more likely refer to the distribution of $X+Y$ where $X$ and $Y$ are both geometric (e.g. count the tosses until you have gotten *two* heads). Your distribution is not the same as this, because you are adding up PMF's, not random variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that it doesn't make sense for $n$ to be $0$. So the formula you found only works for $n\geq 1$.

To show that the sum of the probabilities will be $1$, we find the value of the sum
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty p^n(1-p)+(1-p)^np$$
$$=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(p^n(1-p)+(1-p)^np\right)$$
$$=p(1-p)\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty p^{n-1}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty (1-p)^{n-1}\right)$$
$$=p(1-p)\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty p^n+\sum_{n=0}^\infty (1-p)^n\right)$$
$$=p(1-p)\left(\frac{1}{1-p}+\frac{1}{p}\right)$$
$$=p+(1-p)$$
$$=\boxed{1}$$

So we have shown that the sum of the probabilities will be $1$. I don't believe there is a simpler expression for the formula you found.